# Elastic APM using Java agent : Only a subset of my incoming requests have spans, while the majority of requests do not

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, elastic-apm

Kibana version:7.9.2

Elasticsearch version: 7.9.2

APM Server version: 7.9.2

APM Agent language and version: java agent, version : 1.42.0

I have a Spring MVC application running on Google AppEngine with Java 17 as the runtime. I've configured it with the -javaagent flag. My goal is to monitor and view all the requests and their associated spans in my application. However, I've encountered an issue where I can only see spans for some of the incoming requests. While I can see the overall execution time when filtering by trace IDs, I'm unable to view the specific spans related to those requests. I need assistance in understanding why this is happening and what steps I should take to ensure that I can view spans for all incoming requests.

The default setting for request tracing is to capture all incoming requests. However, I've explicitly set the transaction_sample_rate to 1 to ensure that all requests are sampled for tracing. Surprisingly, even with this configuration, I'm still unable to capture traces for all requests.

These are the configs that I have used:
-javaagent:WEB-INF/lib/elastic-apm-agent-1.42.0.jar -Delastic.apm.service_name=myApp -Delastic.apm.environment=staging -Delastic.apm.server_urls=http://xx.yy.zz.aa:8200 -Delastic.apm.secret_token=******* -Delastic.apm.application_packages=com.hanok -Delastic.apm.trace_methods=com.hanok.*

This is the expected result where I could see all the spans:[image]

Steps to reproduce:

1.Deploy the app using Java agent configs

2.Trigger some http requests

3.Try filtering out using a trace.id

4.This is what I get as the result which does not have spans at all :[image]

Update :

When I run my application locally, it traces all the requests in the APM. Only when it is deployed in AppEngine it creates this issue. I guess it has something to do with the Google app engine. Can someone tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: In your `-Delastic.apm.*` configuration settings I don't see the `transaction_sample_rate` one.

Comment: I explicitly mentioned it for certain deployments of my application, but that approach didn't resolve the issue for me. I attempted the configuration with and without specifying the `transaction_sample_rate`, and in both cases, I encountered the same problem.

Comment: Any chance to try a more recent version, because 7.9.2 is antiquated?

Comment: I went with 7.9.2 since my Elasticsearch cluster was running on 7.9.2. According to this https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_compatibility I think I can go for 7.17.x version of the APM server. Let me try it out. I'll keep you posted. Thanks!

Comment: When I run my application locally, it traces all the requests in the APM. Only when it is deployed in AppEngine it creates this issue. I guess it has something to do with the Google app engine. Can someone tell me what's wrong here?